# apex:repeat tag won't increment apex:variable

Tags: visualforce, repeat

Below is a snippet of code in which an apex:variable is not increment inside an apex:repeat tag. In this case, the var="rowCount" gets incremented without any issues, but the var="headerCount" does not increment at all. Can anyone provide some insight?

**Sample Code**

```
<apex:pageBlock >
      <!-- Tracks the row in the table -->
      <apex:variable var="rowCount" value="{!-1}" />// This variable increments properly
      <apex:variable var="headerCount" value="{!0}" />// This variable does not increment at all

      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="{!Title}" id="pbSec">
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sObjRecords}" var="sObj" styleClass="dataTable table table-fixedheader" id="pageBlockTable">
              <!-- Displays the multiple columns based on the user input -->

              <apex:repeat value="{!Fields}" var="fld">
                  <apex:column >

                    <apex:outputText value="{!sObj[fld]}"/>

                    <apex:facet name="header">{!headers[headerCount]}</apex:facet>
                      <apex:variable var="headerCount" value="{!headerCount+1}" />
                  </apex:column>
              </apex:repeat>

              <!-- Action Column with buttons - May not be used if attribute is false -->
              <apex:column rendered="{!IsActionColumnEnabled}" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">{!$Label.YAHS_PRT_Action}</apex:facet>
                  <apex:repeat value="{!Buttons}" var="button">

                  <apex:variable var="rowCount" value="{!rowCount+1}" />
```

Comment: Unless you can relate the two, you need a separate apex:repeat for header since they use different variables.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, they are under different repeat tags.

<apex:repeat value="{!Fields}" var="fld"> and <apex:repeat value="{!Buttons}" var="button">

Comment: In this case it would be <apex:repeat value="{!headers}" var="hdrs"> or whatever you want to use. Your header is above where the buttons are located. look at where your first apex:repeat ends. You've not posted all of your code, but each repeat requires a close. I may have misunderstood your question, but I was looking at the one above where your buttons start (above the `</apex:repeat>`).

Comment: Yes, I have a close for all the repeat tags. When I do the repeat as you have suggested, then I seem to get a table within a table, that's why I've been trying to have a param increment.

Comment: That's why I was saying you need to relate `!Fields` to `!headers`. This would normally be done via a wrapper class.

Comment: I appreciate the input, but I am fairly new to Visualforce, so I don't quite follow. Would you be able to elaborate how that would look?

Comment: That's not a simple subject. You create a custom controller to combine your sObj and the headers into a custom "wrapper" class. See https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class for some of the basics. You can also search the forum for tons of posts with examples of wrapper classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41785/discussion-between-kevin-and-crmprogdev).

Answer (score 1):

please refer to Salesforce documentation for [apex:variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm).

*Note: apex:variable does not support reassignment inside of an iteration component, such as apex:dataTable or apex:repeat.
The result of doing so, e.g., incrementing the  as a counter, is unsupported and undefined.*

Regardless of few confusions in your code, this design (using variable inside repeat) will never work perfectly and will always leave a possibility for random failures.

I suggest you to use apex:repeat as it was originally intended - as a repeat over a collection of elements. There is always other way to iterate over something then incrementing a apex:variable.

Comment: How do you recommend I increment a value via the VF page then? Any suggestions?

Comment: I prefer not to do that. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  As I understand, value rowCount will be equal to {!Buttons.size()} and headerCount will be equal to {!Fields.size()}.

Answer (score 0):

The safe way to retrieve a value from a collection of values inside `<apex:repeat>` is to use a `Map`, e.g. `Map<String, String>` in your case, where the key is the field name and the value is the header for the field.  Maps use the same syntax in VisualForce as Lists, so your code looks something like:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myList}" var="myVar">
    <apex:outputText value="myMap[myVar]" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know of any obvious way to duplicate this functionality without a custom controller or extension.  If the value you are iterating over happens to be a primitive or you only need an iterating number, you can use Javascript to get similar functionality:

```
<script>
    var myVarList = new Array();
    var iteratorForList = 0;
    <apex:repeat value="{!myVarList}" var="myVar">
        myVarList.push('{!myVar}');
    </apex:repeat>
</script>
<apex:repeat value="{!otherControllerList}" var="myOtherVar">
    <apex:outputText id="textPlacer" />
    <script>
        document.querySelector('#{!$Component.textPlacer}').innerText = myVarList[iteratorForList];
        iteratorForList++;
    </script>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply re-declare the variable at the end of your repeat iteration and increment it within the repeat like this...

```
    <apex:variable var="iter" value="1" />
    <apex:repeat value="{!myList}" var="lis">
        .... all your page elements here

        <apex:variable value="{!iter+ 1}" var="iter" />
    </apex:repeat>
```

this has worked for me in the past.